# In the expo razorpayment integration is possible or not?

Tags: expo

If possible how to integrate? I tried react-native CLI and it is working but React native expo CLI it does not work. How do I integrate razorpay in Expo Android application?

This code is working in react native CLI but not in react native expo CLI. How to integrate the razorpay in react native Expo? Given the code below, how do I correct it to work in the expo project?

```js
import RazorpayCheckout from "react-native-razorpay";

const handleRecharge = async () => {
  
    console.log(response, "response");
    const amount = 100;
    var options = {
      description: "Credits towards consultation",
      image: "https://i.imgur.com/3g7nmJC.jpg",
      currency: "INR",
      key: "rzp_test_SgQ8lvCX4WN0mP",
      amount: "5000",
      name: "Acme Corp",
      order_id: "order_DslnoIgkIDL8Zt", //Replace this with an order_id created using Orders API.
      prefill: {
        email: "gaurav.kumar@example.com",
        contact: "9191919191",
        name: "Gaurav Kumar",
      },
      theme: { color: "#53a20e" },
    };
    RazorpayCheckout.open({
      ...options,
      amount: 5000, // Change the amount value to a number
    })
      .then((data) => {
        // handle success
        alert(`Success: ${data.razorpay_payment_id}`);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // handle failure
        alert(`Error: ${error.code} | ${error.description}`);
      });
   
  };
```